# Custom Keyboard on iPhone

Tags: iphone, keyboard

What's the easiest way to implement a custom keyboard on the iPhone?  I basically want an action sheet that keeps part of my interface visible, but I want to load my own view into it, preferably via nib.  I've been looking into modal views, but I'm getting the feeling I'm going in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a view, add it to your window, and resize the rest of the views in the window to accommodate.